# xamarin ios firebase crash reporting

Tags: firebase, xamarin.ios, crash-reports, firebase-analytics, firebase-crash-reporting

I added firebase crash reporting in my xamarin ios project, it seems everything is fine but no logs in console ... I also have push notifications implements and it works fine.. 
In AppDelegate I call initialization:

```
        Firebase.Analytics.App.Configure();
```

Here is packages i added :

```
rgetFramework="xamarinios10" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Firebase.iOS.CloudMessaging" version="1.2.2" targetFramework="xamarinios10" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Firebase.iOS.Core" version="3.5.2" targetFramework="xamarinios10" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Firebase.iOS.CrashReporting" version="1.1.5.1" targetFramework="xamarinios10" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Firebase.iOS.InstanceID" version="1.0.9" targetFramework="xamarinios10" />
```

Also, I add before build command as it is documented in [components page](https://components.xamarin.com/view/firebaseioscrashreporting)

```
sh ${ProjectDir}/scripts/FirebaseCrashReporting/xamarin_upload_symbols.sh -n ${ProjectName} -b ${TargetDir} -i ${ProjectDir}/Info.plist -p ${ProjectDir}/GoogleService-Info.plist -s ${ProjectDir}/service-account.json
```

Also, uploaded debug symbols from terminal :

```
sh scripts/FirebaseCrashReporting/xamarin_upload_symbols.sh -n App.iOS  -b bin/iPhone/Debug -i Info.plist -p GoogleService-Info.plist -s service-account.json
```

It takes longer but is done. Is there any problems regarding package versions of something known issue?

If i call log after configuration in AppDelegate inside Finishing launching

```
public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication application, NSDictionary launchOptions)
    {
        Firebase.Analytics.App.Configure();

        Firebase.CrashReporting.CrashReporting.Log("blah");
}
```

log says that something in wrong :

> 2017-08-24 16:27:55.611 MYAPP.iOS[285:50120] You've implemented
>   -[ application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:], but
>   you still need to add "remote-notification" to the list of your
>   supported UIBackgroundModes in your Info.plist. Resolved pending
>   breakpoint at 'AppDelegate.cs:141,1' to void
>   MYAPP.iOS.AppDelegate.<>c.b__17_0 (object sender,
>   Foundation.NSNotificationEventArgs e) [0x00007]. 2017-08-24
>   16:27:56.048:  FIRMessaging library version 1.2.2
>   2017-08-24 16:27:56.068 MYAPP.iOS[285:50120] *** -[NSKeyedUnarchiver
>   initForReadingWithData:]: data is NULL 2017-08-24 16:27:56.069:
>    FIRMessaging AppDelegate proxy enabled, will
>   swizzle app delegate remote notification receiver handlers. Add
>   "FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled" to your Info.plist and set it to NO
>   2017-08-24 16:27:56.070 Chronos.iOS[285] 
>   [Firebase/Crash][I-CRA000004] Successfully initialized
>   ** Unknown exception behavior: 0

Answer (score 0):

From the log, it seems like the only problem is this message:

> You've implemented -[
>   application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:], but
>   you still need to add "remote-notification" to the list of your
>   supported UIBackgroundModes in your Info.plist. Resolved pending
>   breakpoint at 'AppDelegate.cs:141,1' to void MYAPP.iOS.AppDelegate

Other messages seem to be just some additional information from Firebase Message SDK.

> *** -[NSKeyedUnarchiver initForReadingWithData:]: data is NULL
>   Is a message from XCode that the one of the SDKs is using the keychain and provides a nil object to that method.